# Finding out how many users have the same phone number, and how many numbers belong to one user in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that logs calls and I'm trying to map the called numbers to the users answering them. To do this I need to display a table that shows me two seperate questions.

I guess the relevant columns in the existing table are "phone_number" and "user_email". Lets say we have around 400 numbers and 450 users.

Example Original Table, name would be "callsoftware_calls":

```
| User_Email | phone_number |
| -------- | -------- |
| John@gmail.com   | 1800 400   |
| John@gmail.com   | 1800 400   |
| John@gmail.com   | 1800 700   |
| Mary@gmail.com  | 1800 600  |
| Mary@gmail.com   | 1800 400   |
| Mary@gmail.com   | 1800 300   |
```

Ideal table outputs for the two queries would be:

```
| User | Count of assigned Numbers |
| -------- | -------- |
| John@gmail.com  | 8   |
| Mary@gmail.com   | 3   |
```

and

```
| PhoneNumber | Count of unique emails/users |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1800 400   | 10   |
| 1800 300   | 6   |
```

any ideas on how to generate these two tables?

Honestly I don't know where to start in generating such a query. I'm used to excel and just getting started with sql so trying to do basic analysis

Comment: You need to tag what DBMS you are using and also give us more information about the table. Example would be the name of the table, how is it structured.

Comment: sorry, i tagged it. using snowflake

Comment: This looks very basic. You aggreate per phone number or email address and count distinct email addresses resp. phone numbers. Or am I missing something?

Comment: i have to admit im very new to this so im struggling to find the code that allows me to output such code @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Then you should read some SQL tutorial, I guess. You aggregate by phone numbers with `GROUP BY phone_number`. You count distinct email addresses with `COUNT(DISTINCT user_email)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm checking your tables, and SQL allows us to count a field and grouping by another field.

```
--Example
WITH users AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
        (1, 'John@gmail.com', '1800 400'), 
        (2, 'John@gmail.com', '1800 400'), 
        (3, 'John@gmail.com', '1800 700'), 
        (4, 'Mary@gmail.com', '1800 600'), 
        (5, 'Mary@gmail.com', '1800 400'), 
        (6, 'Mary@gmail.com', '1800 300')
    
    ) AS _ (user_id, userEmail, phone)
)
--query that makes a grouping by userEmail and counts the phones 
--Qry count phone----------------------------------------------
select 
    userEmail, count(phone) as [Count of assigned Numbers] 
from 
    users
group by 
    userEmail
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

The query to count the users is very similar just change the fields

```
select 
    phone, count(userEmail) as [Count of unique emails/users] 
from 
    users
group by 
    phone
```

Best Regards

Comment: I doubt that snowflake supports those non-standard brackets that you are using for your column aliases. Better use an alias that doesn't need quoting anyway, such as phone_number_count. And if I am not mistaken the task is about distinct email addresses and phone numbers, so use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem (the data does not seem to line up with the desired results, but I think that's just because it's abbreviated), this is a standard `group by` query. Group by one or the other column:

```
create or replace table T1 as 
select 
COLUMN1::string as User_Email,
COLUMN2::string as phone_number
from (values
('John@gmail.com','1800 400'),
('John@gmail.com','1800 400'),
('John@gmail.com','1800 700'),
('Mary@gmail.com','1800 600'),
('Mary@gmail.com','1800 400'),
('Mary@gmail.com','1800 300')
);

select User_Email, count(*) as ASSIGNED_NUMBERS from T1 group by User_Email;
select phone_number, count(*) as COUNT_OF_UNIQUE_EMAILS from T1 group by phone_number;
```

Output:

| USER_EMAIL | ASSIGNED_NUMBERS |
| --- | --- |
| John@gmail.com | 3 |
| Mary@gmail.com | 3 |

| PHONE_NUMBER | COUNT_OF_UNIQUE_EMAILS |
| --- | --- |
| 1800 400 | 3 |
| 1800 700 | 1 |
| 1800 300 | 1 |
| 1800 600 | 1 |